# run a .sh file using java

Tags: java, bash, terminal, command

I want to run a .sh file using java. I want a terminal to be opened and then I can execute another commands in the same terminal and finally destroy it. 
I already used ProcessBuilder but I could not accomplish this.
My piece of code:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/home/omar/ros_ws/baxter2.sh");
Process p = pb.start();
```

This method used to work in another code, but I don't know why it's not working in mine.

Thanks in advance

Comment: yes, i have no errors in java. it just has no effect. Once I run the code it ends normally without executing the .sh file. I see no terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you know that it doesn't execute? Maybe you just aren't seeing its result. You should get `p.getInputStream()` after executing and print in your console, like:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
   System.out.println(line);
}
```

Also if you're using jdk 7+, try:

```
pb.redirectOutput(Redirect.INHERIT);
pb.redirectError(Redirect.INHERIT);
Process p = pb.start();
```

Comment: This already printed the output. And I figured something. I made a script that contains only pwd which prints the current directory and the output was "/home/omar/workspace/script runner" which is the directory of eclipse workspace not it's root directory. How can I fix that.

Comment: You mean the prior problem got solved? I'm not sure I understood what you explained but it seems to be another problem and maybe needs posting another question ...

Answer (score 1):

Does your program output an error, or is your program not interacting with the file?

I would suggest trying the directory method within ProcessBuilder.

```
Process p = null;
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("baxter2.sh");
pb.directory("/home/omar/ros_ws");
p = pb.start();
```

If this doesn't work, you should also look into user permissions for the file that you're trying to access.

Comment: The same thing. No errors and it has no permission issues.

Comment: The point is that when I change the path to a .sh file that does not exist it throws IOException

Answer (score 0):

I think you should grant the .sh file the executable permission to the OS user used to run the java program by using the below command.

chmod u+x baxter2.sh